# How to find boundedness conditions of a function involving Hypergeometric function

Tags: special-functions

To obtain boundedness conditions (relation among constants or parameters) of  function involving Hypergeometric function

$$c_0 + c_{\pm} e^{\pm \lambda \xi } \, _2F_1\left[\frac{1}{n-1},\frac{2}{n-1};\frac{n}{n-1};\frac{\alpha  \left( \pm c_{\pm} \lambda  e^{\pm \lambda \xi } \right)^{n-1}}{2(n+1) \lambda^2}\right]$$
where $c_0, \, c_{\pm}, \lambda, n>1(real)$ are  constants.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this about Wolfram Mathematica? If so, please provide code sample to work with and make sure "boundedness conditions" is clear for wider audience.

Comment: The Hypergeometric function `2F1[a,b;c; x]` converges when `Abs[z] < 1 || (Abs[z] == 1 && Re[c - a - b] > 0)` if this is what you asking for "boundedness"...

Comment: Thanks to Kuba and J.A.D.Navas. I obtained this result, solving a nonlinear differential equation using Mathematica code. Now, I want to Plot this solution (in Mathematica) in order to obtain a bounded physical solution. For this reason, I want to obtain the conditions for which it will be bounded.

Comment: @Ragat don't use answers to add information, edit the question instead. My  wish about valid code to work with remains.